# In an asp.net Razor view, is there anyway to simply continue on error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So, vb has the much discussed "on error resume next", right now I really need something like that in a C# razor view.

It probably doesn't exists, buy maybe there is another way to accomplish something similar?

I'm trying to create a simple Razor View that is a read only page just for printing. However this view will have a LOT of fields, several hundred rows like this:

```
 <td class="label">Sales Rep #1:</td>
 <td class="val">@Model.salesRep1.name</td>
```

The problem is that salesRep might be null, and this will throw an error. The amount of code on the page will drastically increase if I have wrap each field in an `@{if(Model.salesRep1.firstName != null){}}` statement.

It would be super slick to just add `on error resume next` to the top of the page and not worry about the nulls. Is there any similar solution?

Thanks,

Comment: No, and nor should there be. Handle these problems when you build up the ViewModel!

Comment: Can't you place `@if(Model.salesRep1 == null) Model.salesRep1 = new XXX();` at the beginning of the file?

Comment: @MenelaosVergis - that's *not* display logic, and thus shouldnt be in a view. However, thats just the sort of thing you should do when building up the ViewModel.

Comment: In addition to Jamiec's comment the view is for displaying the view model data. The controller is responsible for setting up the view model. The view model typically contains no business logic just like the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View's should only contain view logic, and even that should only extend to outputting properties from the ViewModel.

The controller is often responsible for building up this viewmodel, and it is at that point that you should default any properties where you want to ensure that they are not null when trying to display them.

So for example, in a controller you might have:

```
var emptySalesRep = new SalesRep();

var model = new MyModel();
model.salesRep1 = repository.GetSalesRep1() ?? emptySalesRep;
```

Now, it might be that you have a lot of this, so you might choose to instead leave `salesRep1` null, and have another way of dealing with this in the View without resporting to lots of `if(Model.salesRep1 != null){ ... }`.

An extension method could be used (although I prefer the approach above)

```
public static string DisplayForWhenNotNull<T>(this HtmlHelper html, Func<T> obj, Func<T,object> prop)
{
    var item = obj();
    if(item == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return prop(item);
}
```

Usage:

```
<td class="label">Sales Rep #1:</td>
<td class="val">@Html.DisplayForWhenNotNull(() => Model.salesRep1, sr => sr.name)</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for nulls in the view, or try to ignore errors, I'd use a viewmodel and make sure that salesRep isn't null in there.